# Is Bot Framework composer project dead?

Tags: botframework

If you are a kind maintainer of this project then can you please enlightened us to know if all the open issues will be addressed or not? I don't see any merge pulled request or any open issues fixed.

Are we moving away from this project by abandoning? any other alternatives?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Referring back to what Dana says, it would seem that the Bot Framework Composer is in a state of maintenance: there will be no further evolutions but it will be supported until it is fully part of Copilot Studio.
To me this seems only partially true. That Composer has been abandoned I am sure but I am equally certain that no one is supporting it.
In the meantime, though, Composer still supports .Net Core 3.1 which is officially unsupported: version 2.1.2 of Composer, the official one, does not work because, due to an expired certificate it is not possible to load external components via nuget, the nightly version 2.1.3 solves this problem but there are other issues, such as the fact that some language generator functions are no longer supported (one on all the "fromFile").
Finally, my Azure Bot built entirely with Composer which was working perfectly until two three months ago, has stopped working on Azure since a few days ago, working perfectly on local using the Bot Framework Emulator and, we still couldn't figure out what hell we got ourselves into.

Comment: sorry to hear that...absolutely horrible way to deliver something.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft CoPilot Studio (formerly "Power Virtual Agents") with the integrated Bot Framework Composer capabilities such as inline expressions, adaptive cards, property management, and so on went GA in May at Build, and is where the latest iteration of our Composer capabilities (including CLU support, Generative AI, etc) are available. Our guidance to customers and the field is all new bot starts should start with CoPilot Studio as of the GA release.

The current in-market Composer is considered complete as-is; we do not have a roadmap of new features to introduce. We’ll continue to provide support and critical bug fixes, but are not planning further feature adds.

Comment: Thank you @Dana, may I please know what is GA release means. Further, isn't CoPilot Studio is paid while composer is free. I am starting a new bot from scratch with almost no knowledge. I strongly suggest we put some kind of note in the main GitHub page to help. Also, what about Framework SDK development, is it still around or will move to CoPilot. Thanks again for answering.